# Recommended Way To Integrate Dynamics CRM/365 With SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, dynamics-365

What is the Microsoft recommended way to integrate between Dynamics CRM/365 and SharePoint Online when some customisation is required?

Comment: What exactly do you want to customized. Than Standard integration allows storing documents with SharePoint document libraries and working in Onenote.

Answer (score 1):

The only out of the box way to integrate Dynamics 365 and SharePoint online is to use the out of the box features: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/set-up-dynamics-365-online-to-use-sharepoint-online

However, from a SharePoint perspective this lacks a lot of best practices and doesn't support any customizations:

- One library with a folder per entity
- By default a guid is attached to the folder name
- No customizations
- No metadata

My personal approach is to use a custom provisions for SharePoint and use the default integration to connect the two. I tend to use Azure Functions for this. See my blog post for more detail: https://www.oak3.org/azure/creating-sharepoint-site-dynamics-crm-azure-functions/

Answer (score 0):

If your organizations wish to deploy for the first time or upgrade to server-based SharePoint integration. After you enable server-based SharePoint integration, you can’t revert to the previous client-based authentication method.

You review the docs [Set up Dynamics 365 (online) to use SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/set-up-dynamics-365-online-to-use-sharepoint-online).

If you can’t use server-based SharePoint integration, you must install the Microsoft Dynamics CRM List Component to get document management functionality. The Microsoft Dynamics CRM List Component is a SharePoint solution that you upload and activate on a SharePoint site collection. This feature uses a client-to-SharePoint Server strategy to authenticate and transmit data.

You can review docs [Configure SharePoint integration using the list component](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/configure-sharepoint-integration-using-list-component).